# How do I remove the GDPR Warning from Admob Console?

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform, ump

[image]

5 days ago, I go a warning at the top of my console saying

**Later this year, Google will require all publishers serving ads to EEA and UK users to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP). You can use any Google-certified CMP for this purpose, including Google's own consent management solution. If you are interested in using Google's consent management solution, start by setting up your GDPR message and implementing the UMP SDK. Learn more**

I have create the GDPR dialog from **privacy and messages** section from admob console, but the warning is just still there, How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Google AdMob Help Community - Check out this for both question and answer

[Implement GDPR message (Both SDK and Message part) but warning is still on my Admob account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76576575/implement-gdpr-message-both-sdk-and-message-part-but-warning-is-still-on-my-ad/76582082#76582082)

Comment: Thanks, ever since this warning appeared ecpm has been dropping and overall earnings reducing for all my apps. Do you experience the same too?

Comment: Yes, Same experience

Comment: Alright then, thank goodness is a general issue, maybe it will be resolved soon. Thanks.

Comment: Noman Baig, I also noticed more than 20 apps that are not mine showing up in the **Apps To Confirm** section in admob console. Can you please check if it is the same with yours?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand can you please explain more? also tell me where apps to confirm section is.

Comment: **Apps to confirm** is located in **Apps > View all apps > Apps to confirm** please check and tell me if it is the same for you? So many apps that are not mine are showing up there for me to confirm. I had them blocked from showing ads already anyway. I still cannot understand why my ecpm dropped so bad and I am currently earning half of what i used to earn 2 weeks ago since the GDPR warning started showing up.

Comment: I checked and I didnt have any problem like that. but yeah earnings dropped after a warning. btw my warning is gone now so maybe it will be ok now

Comment: alright thats great, in a total of how many days or weeks did the warning stay after complying with the GDPR consent?

Comment: About two weeks

Comment: GDPR warning came back to my AdMob ):

Comment: What? Why? Show your code on how you implement the GDPR consent.

Comment: Everything is working properly bro. I am getting the stats of users who is able to see those consent messages. more then 100 people already consent

Comment: just give it time, maybe the warning will pass.

Comment: Yeah, It's gone again.

Comment: thats good, but mine still here, can you please show me how you implemented consent? maybe i'm doing something wrong in mine.

Comment: There is one problem in the code which is provided by Google. question and answer both are available on my StackOverflow profile. Check it out maybe it will helpful

Comment: has earning returned back to normal?

Comment: It's still kind of disturbing

Comment: maybe it will improve, if it does please let me know. Mine has been 1 week since i added the GDPR consent implementation in all my apps so I am still waiting for the remaining 1 week.

Comment: Sure, I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/EXQrn93cr0A

watch this brother
first create a GDPR message from admob. Then Implement UMP SDK correctly, then 2 week inside autometicaly gone the notification.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).