# Implement GDPR message (Both SDK and Message part) but warning is still on my Admob account

Tags: android, admob

"Later this year, Google will require all publishers serving ads to EEA and UK users to use a Google-certified Consent Management Platform (CMP). You can use any Google-certified CMP for this purpose, including Google's own consent management solution. If you are interested in using Google's consent management solution, start by setting up your GDPR message and implementing the UMP SDK. Learn more"

**Warning is still on my Admob Account.**

**Things I Did Already**

- Implemented and tested the GDPR message successfully.
- Published updated apps to Google Play
- One of my app was on ionic so i unpublished that app from EU and UK

After waiting 2-3 days, Warning is still on my Admob Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from Google AdMob Help Community

This is what they said ↓ you can see this in the screenshot also

"For now its general message and show for all publishers.
if you Implement the GDPR dont worry about that"

[image: ScreenShot of that answer]

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Before posting answers, please refer to how to answer section here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think now it's ok